# Display the number of registered users

Tags: bash, command-line, users, display

How can I display the number of registered users on the system who have their home directory in /home and simultaneously have Bash Shell as the command interpreter?

Comment: Is this your homeworks ?

Comment: Using the `awk` command against the /etc/passwd file for example ?

Comment: @GillesQuenot No, it is an exam question

Comment: It's the same ^^

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: The only thing that I tried was `cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd`

Comment: first define "registered" vs "unregistered" users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just `grep` the `/etc/password` file for lines that have `:/home` (so a field that starts with `/home`), then more non-`:` characters and only one more `:` before the end, which should be followed by `/bin/bash`:

```
$ grep ':/home/[^:]*:/bin/bash' /etc/passwd
terdon:x:1000:1000::/home/terdon:/bin/bash
bib:x:1001:1001::/home/bib:/bin/bash
```

So, to display the number only:

```
$ grep -c ':/home/[^:]*:/bin/bash' /etc/passwd
2
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `getent` and `awk`:

```
getent passwd | awk -F: '$6 ~ "^/home/" && $7 ~ "bash$"{print $1}'
```

This will look for all users with `/home/` as a path in their home directory and their shell set to bash, and print a list of usernames.

If you only want it to return simply the number of users you can modify the `awk` program to:

```
getent passwd | awk -F: '$6 ~ "^/home/" && $7 ~ "bash$"{c+=1}END{print c}'
```

Comment: Thank you mate, I will look now what those commands do to understand the answer

Comment: @whoami If one of the answers solved your issue, please take a moment to [accept it](//$$SITEURL/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on [the checkmark on the left](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/203101). That will mark the question as answered and is the way that thanks are conveyed on the Stack Exchange sites.